# Format HTML file(s) from the command line

Tags: html, command-line, formatter

I want to format HTML source files from the command line, one file at a time or in bulk.

#### Tool requirements

1. Should be installable on Windows, Linux, and macOS.
2. Must be capable of formatting in place, overwriting the current HTML file(s).
3. Should allow setting the indent size to a single space. <sup>1</sup>
4. Should merely *format* the HTML code – not validate it.
5. Must not make any false claims about the HTML code.
6. The `<head>` and `<body>` tags should *not* be indented.
7. The maximum number of line breaks to be preserved may be set to zero.

#### A tool I tried but discarded

I've tried [prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier?activeTab=versions), but it erroneously reported that `<form>` is a [self-closing tag in HTML](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html). <sup>2</sup> 
This I cannot allow, which is why I discarded it.

#### An *online* tool

The *online* formatter I've found to best meet my requirements, is [HTML Formatter](https://webformatter.com/html).

### References

- [The documentation of the NPM package `prettier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier?activeTab=versions)
- [List of HTML Self-Closing Tags](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)
- [An example HTML file](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/SoftwareRecs-Q87737/form-demo.html.zip)
- [The download page for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en)
- [Screenshot from running `prettier`](https://i.imgur.com/FF1lAYL.png)
- [Closing elements that have implied end tags](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags)
- [HTML Formatter – an *online* formatter](https://webformatter.com/html)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The rationale for one-space indents is two-fold.

- I want to keep down the file size.
- When watching the file in a text editor, I want to use up as little horizontal space as possible.

<sup>2</sup>
I installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en), and then globally installed the package [prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier?activeTab=versions) by running :

```
npm install --global prettier
```

Then I downloaded the file [`form-demo.html`](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/SoftwareRecs-Q87737/form-demo.html.zip) – in a zip file, so that the unformatted file can easily be restored.
It has a `<form>` tag with a property `action` set to `/search` (instead of `"/search"`).
I tried to format `form-demo.html` with `prettier` :

```
prettier form-demo.html
```

To that, `prettier` [replied with a syntax error](https://i.imgur.com/FF1lAYL.png), referring to [Closing elements that have implied end tags](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags), but `<form>` is *not* a [self-closing tag](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### *I want a tool that formats HTML files from the command line*

– I recommend [`js-beautify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify/v/1.14.9), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400992). 
I prefer to install it globally:

```
npm install --global js-beautify
```

I typically want to format all `*.html` files in the current folder. <sup>1</sup>

```
js-beautify *.html --type html --replace --indent-size 1 --max-preserve-newlines 0
```

The above fulfills all eight requirements of the question, including the three optional ones.

### References

- [The documentation of the NPM package `js-beautify` – version 1.14.9](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify/v/1.14.9)
- [Answer using `js-beautify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400992)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The command may be written shorter as :

```
js-beautify --type html -r -s 1 -m 0 *.html
```

This formats the HTML to my liking.
Check out [the *Options*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify/v/1.14.9#user-content-options) to find your favorite settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try [html tidy](https://www.html-tidy.org/).

> Tidy is a console application for macOS, Linux, Windows, UNIX, and more. It corrects and cleans up HTML and XML documents by fixing markup errors .

It has many options and is available on [many platforms](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+tidy), and online.

Installation on Windows and integration of its output into an editor such as Textpad was kind of tricky but it can be done .
https://www.google.com/search?q=html+tidy

I am not sure about your requirement "indent 1 character" but I think this can be worked around by indenting with tabs, and then global  substitution with of tab with 1 blank.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.
In [my example HTML file](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/SoftwareRecs-Q87737/form-demo.html.zip),
the title tag, <title>"prettier" says \`<form>\` is a self-closing tag.</title>, causes problems because I used a backtick and `<` instead of `&lt;`.
In this respect, js-beautify is more forgiving than tidy,
and for now, I prefer js-beautify to tidy.
But for someone wanting to *validate* HTML, I can see how tidy is preferable to js-beautify.
Screenshots:
https://i.imgur.com/etHKMzD.png, https://i.imgur.com/RSMkfhT.png.